# Draggable Scrollable sheet closes automatically

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

Draggable Scrollable sheet closes automatically after opening it with tap and jumpTo function but works perfectly on drag

```
final DraggableScrollableController _sheetcontroller =DraggableScrollableController();

/// Bottom sheet configration

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final panelHeightClosed = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .08;
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(widget.title),
          ),
          body: const MapView(),
          bottomSheet: DraggableScrollableSheet(
              controller: _sheetcontroller,
              initialChildSize: .1,
              minChildSize: .1,
              maxChildSize: 1,
              snapSizes: const [
                .6,
              ],
              expand: false,
              builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController) =>
                  SingleChildScrollView(
                    controller: scrollController,
                    child: Column(
              
/// The gesture detector to toggle the view of bottom sheet
children: <Widget>[
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 12.0,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => tooglepanel(),
                      child: Row(
                        children: const [
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 10,
                          ),
                          Icon(Icons.menu),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 16,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "Tab to Attendence",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 19.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .08,
                ),

   
/// Layout calls for contents in the bottom sheet
   Card(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          CustomIconAttendence(
                            "assets/profile.png",
                            "Attendence",
                            context,
                          ),
                          CustomIconLeave(
                            "assets/profile.png",
                            "Leave",
                            context,
                          ),
                          CustomIconMarketClose(
                            "assets/profile.png",
                            "Market Close",
                            context,
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 16,
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          CustomIconTraining(
                            "assets/profile.png",
                            "Training",
                            context,
                          ),
                          CustomIconWeekOff(
                            "assets/profile.png",
                            "Week Off",
                            context,
                          ),
                          CustomIconHoliday(
                            "assets/profile.png",
                            "Holiday",
                            context,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 16,
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          CustomIconOnDuty(
                            "assets/profile.png",
                            "On Duty",
                            context,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                  ],
                ),
              )),
    );
  }

//Toggles the view of bottom sheet depending on current size 

  void tooglepanel() {
    if (_sheetcontroller.size == .6) {
      _sheetcontroller.jumpTo(.1);
    } else if (_sheetcontroller.size < .6) {
      _sheetcontroller.jumpTo(.6);
    } else if (_sheetcontroller.size > .6) {
      _sheetcontroller.jumpTo(.1);
    }
  }
}
```

Further info: i am getting warning of Exceeded sample count in frametime

Comment: You want open full on 1st tap while the draggable is closed?

Comment: it is doing what i want it to do that is snapping to the given size ( 0.6 ) but if I tap to open it , it closes automatically ( which is what i want to resolve ) but if I open it using drag it does not or if i drag it after opening it with tap it stays on screen and doesnt minimises to minchildsize

Comment: On second tap, you don't want  to close it?  What do you expect

Comment: I want it to remain open if i open it using either tap or drag , right now drag works fine but on tap it opens up and then closes automatically, it doesnt remain open if i use tap method , but if i interact with it even after using tap method it stays open it doesnt closes itself, so i want to make it not close itself if i tap it to open

Answer (score 0):

Try chaning logic like

```dart
  void tooglepanel() {
    if (_sheetcontroller.size == .6) {
      // _sheetcontroller.jumpTo(.1);
    } else if (_sheetcontroller.size < .6) {
      _sheetcontroller.jumpTo(.6);
    } else if (_sheetcontroller.size > .6) {
      _sheetcontroller.jumpTo(.1);
    }
  }
```

Comment: it isnt working , still closes by itself

Comment: Can you include an gif that are you trying to archive

Comment: well I was able to resolve it , I just took out the draggable sheet widget into a new stateful Widget and now it does not close itself, thank you for your time